# Code Pattern to Define and Use Javscript Callbacks / Hooks

Tags: javascript, best-practice, design-patterns

We are using a third party module, that updates prices via AJAX on product / category pages. No we have to react on this update, to update some custom pricing logic.

Of course we do not want to patch the third party module to insert our code, but to send the vendor a patch with can be generally included.

I was thinking about something like this:

1) Ask the vendor to include some kind of hook

```
if (typeof prices_changed_hook === 'function') {
    prices_changed_hook();
}
```

2) Define in our code the function globally

But this does not seem like a clean approach. What is a better one?

I tried also to use the `jQuery('contentUpdated')` event, but without luck.